# Upload AWS Windows AMI to S3: "provided contains AWS-licensed software and is not exportable"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to upload Windows EC2 to S3. When I run below command it says `provided contains AWS-licensed software and is not exportable.`

```
aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-0407aacd2805fe2 --disk-image-format RAW --s3-export-location S3Bucket=migrationvultr,S3Prefix=exports/
```

Please assist me on this.

Comment: btw why do u want to upload AMI to S3 ? Once u created  AMI .. it is already there for you to be used whenever u want to in future.. You can also create snapshot of your virtual machine.

Comment: I am going to migrate My windows VM to another cloud hosting provider. For that I need to upload my VM with .RAW extension to S3 and from S3 I can do the rest of the migration.

Comment: which cloud azure ?

Comment: No Azure. It is vultr.

Comment: I can migrate Linux instances. But This issue is only for Windows insance.

Comment: You might need to start by _importing_ an image from another system (eg VMWare), make your modifications, then export that image.

Comment: Please give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can migrate your VM out of AWS like this. For this you would need to refer tutorial by your destination cloud provider.

For migrating to Azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/migrate-tutorial-aws-azure

For migrating to Google cloud:
https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.2/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/overview

Comment: Linux instance or Windows Instance?

Comment: both will work.. but this support is for azure and google cloud.. u have to find same support from vultr ..

Comment: I can understand that. But I need to upload windows EC2 RAW image to S3. It is works for Linux AMI.